# Set Reference to document.location.search

Tags: javascript

Throughout my code, I have statements like this:

```
document.location.search="?a="+n;
```

I am trying to shorten (for code golf) it so that I do not have to type out the `document.location.search` every time.

The first thing I thought of was to set `document.location.search` to a variable, and then setting that variable, like this:

```
s=document.location.search;
s="?a="+n;
```

This, of course, does not work, because s is set by the *value* of `document.location.search`, and not its *reference*. Is there a way to set s by reference? Is there some other way I can eliminate repeated instances of `document.location.search`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a function

```
function s(val) {
    document.location.search = "?a=" + val;
}
```

and call

```
s('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten it a bit more by setting it like this:

```
s=document.location
s.search="?a="+n;
```